# What is the inverse of the cantor function? (if it exists)

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

The [cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) can be defined in $c(x) : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ by

1. Express $x$ in base 3.
2. If $x$ contains a 1, replace every digit after the first 1 by 0.
3. Replace all 2s with 1s.
4. Interpret the result as a binary number. The result is $c(x)$.

or, equivalently, by the cumulative function of the cantor set.

How do I compute its inverse, $c^{-1}(y)$? does it exists?

(this problem was motivated by trying to sample from the cantor set using [inverse transforming sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling))

Comment: What would you say $c^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})$ is? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function the graph is horizontal at y=1/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cantor function is continuous and monotone increasing. It is constant on each middle ternary interval with a value which is a dyadic rational. Any inverse is therefore discontinuous at dyadic rationals and you have to decide what the value of the inverse should be on those points. Some possible choices:
$$ \phi_-(y) = \sup \{x\in[0,1]: c(x)<y \} \leq 
  \phi_+(y)= \inf \{x\in [0,1] : c(x) >y \} $$
which pick respectively the minimum and maximum possible inverse value at dyadic rationals.